# Why does my function come up as 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried my best for many hours to try get my code to place the html text inside the `context.filltext`, but for some reason, it appears as `undefined` on the screen.

This is my code so far:

```js
var question001 = ["6-8", "10/2", "3+7", "5-3"];
var answer001 = ["-2", "5", "10", "2"];
var random001 = Math.floor(Math.random() * question001.length);

function submit001() {
  var b = input001.value;
  if (random001 == 0 && b == answer001[0]) {
    document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "Correct..";
    document.getElementById("button001").innerHTML = "<button onclick=btn001()>Next</button>";
    document.getElementById("disappear002").innerHTML = "";

  } else if (random001 == 1 && b == answer001[1]) {
    document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "Correct..";
    document.getElementById("button001").innerHTML = "<button onclick=btn001()>Next</button>";
    document.getElementById("disappear002").innerHTML = "";

  } else if (random001 == 2 && b == answer001[2]) {
    document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "Correct..";
    document.getElementById("button001").innerHTML = "<button onclick=btn001()>Next</button>";
    document.getElementById("disappear002").innerHTML = "";

  } else if (random001 == 3 && b == answer001[3]) {
    document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "Correct..";
    document.getElementById("button001").innerHTML = "<button onclick=btn001()>Next</button>";
    document.getElementById("disappear002").innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "Incorrect..";
    document.getElementById("button001").innerHTML = "<button onclick=btn001()>Next</button>";
    document.getElementById("disappear002").innerHTML = "";
  }
}

document.getElementById("name001").innerHTML = question001[random001];

function btn001() {
  random001 = Math.floor(Math.random() * question001.length);
  document.getElementById("name001").innerHTML = question001[random001];
  document.getElementById("button001").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("disappear001").innerHTML = "<input type=text id=input001 autofocus>";
  document.getElementById("disappear002").innerHTML = "<button onclick=submit001()>Submit</button>";
  document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = "";
}

function question() {
  document.getElementById("message001").textContent;
}
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.font = '30px arial';
let scrollCounter, cameraY, current, mode, xSpeed;
let ySpeed = 5;
let height = 50;
let boxes = [];



boxes[0] = {
  x: 300,
  y: 300,
  width: 200
};
let debris = {
  x: 300,
  width: 0
};

function newBox() {
  boxes[current] = {
    x: 0,
    y: (current + 10) * height,
    width: boxes[current - 1].width
  };
}

function gameOver() {
  mode = 'gameOver';
  context.fillText('Your tower collapsed! Wanna play again?', 200, 40);
}

function animate() {
  if (mode != 'gameOver') {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillText('Score: ' + (current - 1).toString(), 10, 40);
    for (let n = 0; n < boxes.length; n++) {
      let box = boxes[n];
      context.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + n * 12 + ',' + n * 89 + ',' + n * 26 + ')';
      context.fillRect(box.x, 600 - box.y + cameraY, box.width, height);
      context.fillText(question(), 300, 340);
    }
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb';
    context.fillRect(debris.x, 600 - debris.y + cameraY, debris.width, height);
    if (mode == 'bounce') {
      boxes[current].x = boxes[current].x + xSpeed;
      if (xSpeed > 0 && boxes[current].x + boxes[current].width > canvas.width)
        xSpeed = -xSpeed;
      if (xSpeed < 0 && boxes[current].x < 0)
        xSpeed = -xSpeed;
    }
    if (mode == 'fall') {
      boxes[current].y = boxes[current].y - ySpeed;
      if (boxes[current].y == boxes[current - 1].y + height) {
        mode = 'bounce';
        let difference = boxes[current].x - boxes[current - 1].x;
        if (Math.abs(difference) >= boxes[current].width) {
          gameOver();
        }
        debris = {
          y: boxes[current].y,
          width: difference
        };
        if (boxes[current].x > boxes[current - 1].x) {
          boxes[current].width = boxes[current].width - difference;
          debris.x = boxes[current].x + boxes[current].width;
        } else {
          debris.x = boxes[current].x - difference;
          boxes[current].width = boxes[current].width + difference;
          boxes[current].x = boxes[current - 1].x;
        }

        current++;
        scrollCounter = height;
        newBox();
      }
    }
    debris.y = debris.y - ySpeed;
    if (scrollCounter) {
      cameraY++;
      scrollCounter--;
    }
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function restart() {
  boxes.splice(1, boxes.length - 1);
  mode = 'bounce';
  cameraY = 0;
  scrollCounter = 0;
  xSpeed = 5;
  current = 1;
  newBox();
  debris.y = 0;
}

document.getElementById("disappear002").onclick = function() {
  if (mode == 'gameOver')
    restart();
  else {
    if (mode == 'bounce')
      mode = 'fall';
  }
};

restart();
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500" style="border:80px solid #ffffff;"></canvas>

<body bgcolor="”#696969&quot;">
  <p style="width: 259px; vertical-align:top">

    <p id="message001">What is <text id="name001">5-3</text>.</p>
    <div id="disappear001"><input type="text" id="input001" autofocus></div>
    <div id="disappear002"><button onclick="submit001 ()">Submit</button></div>

    <p id="answer001"></p>
    <p id="button001"></p>
```

Comment: Which function is `undefined`? `context.fillText`?

Comment: Don't have tags that belong inside the body, outside the body

Comment: Also 
`document.getElementById("answer001").innerHTML = answer001[random001 ] ===  input001.value ? "Correct" : "Incorrect";`

Comment: Hi Khaled! This example is *huge* you should generally have smaller examples for Stack Overflow so people can read your problem and focus just on what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the value of `textContent` in your `question` function. Currently doesn't return anything

```
function question() {
   return document.getElementById("message001").textContent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning any value from

```
function question() {
  document.getElementById("message001").textContent;
}
```

It should be :-

```
function question() {
  return document.getElementById("message001").textContent;
}
```